# searching in memory at verilog

Tags: verilog, memory, ram, synthesis, ise

I need to make a module which responsible to search overall memory to find a specific value and return the address location, but I have the following error after do Synthesize in Xilinx.

```
Loop count limit exceeded. Condition is never false.
```

the Search module: responsible to take the value input and do search on the RAM memory, and return address.

```
module Search(
    clk,
    rst,
    SearchData,
    FindAddress,
     StopSearch
);
input           clk;
input           rst;
input[7:0]      SearchData;
output reg [1:0]   FindAddress;
output reg StopSearch;
integer i;

wire read_rq;
reg [1:0] nxt_address;

initial
begin nxt_address=0;i=0; end

wire[7:0] read_data_inx;

D0_RAM1 D0(
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .read_rq(read_rq),
    .write_rq(0),
    .rw_address(nxt_address),
    .write_data(0),
    .read_data(read_data_inx)
);
always @(posedge clk )
begin
    while (nxt_address <4) begin
        if (read_data_inx == SearchData)  begin //master i has priority
            FindAddress <= nxt_address;
            StopSearch=1;
      end
        else begin
          StopSearch=0;
        end

        nxt_address <= nxt_address+1; 
    end
end 
endmodule
```

and the RAM module:

```
module D0_RAM1(
    clk,
    rst,
    read_rq,
    write_rq,
    rw_address,
    write_data,
    read_data
);
input           clk;
input           rst;
input           read_rq;
input           write_rq;
input[1:0]      rw_address; //2 bit 
input[7:0]      write_data;
output[7:0]     read_data;

reg[7:0]     read_data;

integer out, i;

// Declare memory 2^2 x8 bits
// 2^2 = 4
reg [7:0] memory_ram_d [3:0];
reg [7:0] memory_ram_q [3:0];

// Use positive edge of clock to read the memory
// Implement cyclic shift right
always @(posedge clk or
    negedge rst)
begin
    if (!rst)
    begin
        for (i=0;i<3; i=i+1)
            memory_ram_q[i] <= 0;
    end
    else
    begin
        for (i=0;i<3; i=i+1)
             memory_ram_q[i] <= memory_ram_d[i];
    end
end
//q=d

always @(*)
begin
    for (i=0;i<3; i=i+1)
        memory_ram_d[i] = memory_ram_q[i];
    if (write_rq && !read_rq)
        memory_ram_d[rw_address] = write_data;
    if (!write_rq && read_rq)
        read_data = memory_ram_q[rw_address];
end

endmodule
```

the while statement which caused the previous error.

Comment: Are you trying to search the entire memory in one clock cycle, or are you trying to search one address per clock cycle and stop when you find the target value?

Comment: I don't think about this anymore..
I forgot that I deal with hardware not software, 
it can't be in one cycle the whole searching?

Comment: Without a very [special kind of memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory), no, you can't search through the whole memory in one clock cycle.

Comment: So I have to make another block that has to trigger the searching module each cycle until found the desired value.

Comment: `while` is not synthesizable. `while` is for test benches and behavioral modeling, not synthesizable design.

Comment: @Hanaa, you need to think about what your design requirements are and how actual hardware components can be used to achieve your requirements. Since you haven't said what your design goal is, we can't tell you what hardware you need. We can only tell you why your code is not implementable in real hardware.

Comment: @Greg , what i can use instead of while loop?

Comment: @ThePhoton, Actually I need to implement LZW compress algorithm. for each read character it needs to check the RAM if it consist of this value or not, then if not, then add this value on specific address.

Comment: @Hanaa, instead of the `while` loop you (probably) need to make a state machine that does one step of calculation for each clock edge.

Comment: How? do you mean need to check one location address each clock edge?

Comment: @ThePhoton makes a valid point. You only have one memory read port and you're trying to read all four addresses from it in one clock - the while loop flattened. Increasing the number of read ports wouldn't scale up as you increase the number of addresses.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg [1:0] nxt_address;
...
while (nxt_address <4) begin
```

`nxt_address` is a 2-bit value. It can contain the numbers 0, 1, 2 and 3.  Therefore it will *always* be less than 4.

Which is exactly what the error is saying.

Comment: aah, thanks for your comment, but how to solve this?

Comment: Use a 3 bit counter so it can reach 4, or use some other looping method that finishes at 3 and yet still executes the fourth iteration

Comment: I use reg [2:0]counter, and I have this error 
Non-constant loop condition not supported for while